# Which tends to infinity higher, dividing by almost zero or infinite integral of one?

Tags: limits

is it possible to know which of the two tends to infinity faster ?

1. $$\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{1}{a}$$
2. $$\lim_{a\to 0}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}} dx$$

Comment: It certainly is possible to know. Just evaluate the integral and compare the resulting expression. BTW, I assume you meant “tends”, not “intends”.

Comment: Ya, "tends" . thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}}dx = \frac{1}{a},$$ $\lim\limits_{a\to 0}\int_{0}^{1/a}dx=\lim\limits_{a\to 0}\frac{1}{a}$ and both expressions tend to infinity "at the same speed".

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

They're equal expressions, so they tend to $\infty$ at the same rate.

Comment: “No” is a false answer to “is it possible to know”.

Comment: You're right.  It is possible to know.  @celtschk